# Не работает forEach js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        num_of_points = 72;
        for (var i = -num_of_points/2; i < num_of_points/2; i++) {
            for (var i2 = -num_of_points/2; i2 < num_of_points/2; i2++) {
                array[i + '-' + i2] = [];
                array[i + '-' + i2]['x'] = i * 100;
                array[i + '-' + i2]['y'] = i2 * 100;
            }
        }
        array.forEach(function output(value){
            console.log(value);
        });
```

Не выводит ни ошибок, ничего. Кроме того, если вывести массив просто в консоль (без forEach) то выведет без проблем. Но мне нужно будет потом его именно перебрать - пока что вот такая проблема

Comment: Где объявление переменных и массивов? Как индекс массива array ровно пустому индексу? Разве строки могут быть индексом массива ? Вторые квадратные скобки где х и у разве такое бывает в js ? Я то думал что хоть эти вещи знаю нормально, в гугле не нашел этому объяснение? ИЛИ ЭТО НЕ СОВСЕМ JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) проходит только по существующим элементам массива.

Так как данный массив пуст - `length` == 0, он ничего и не выводит.

Почему массив пуст?

массив считается пустым, так как нет числовых свойств, вместо них добавлены строковые.

В данном случае вместо массива стоило использовать объект `{}`.

Для обхода по свойствам можно воспользоваться циклом [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

---

Либо, если необходим именно массив, стоит добавлять в него элементы, с помощью метода [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 3):

Все ответы уже даны, но просто для разнообразия:

```js
var num_of_points = 72;
var map = new Map();
for (var i = -num_of_points / 2; i < num_of_points / 2; i++) {
  for (var i2 = -num_of_points / 2; i2 < num_of_points / 2; i2++) {
    map.set(i + '-' + i2, {
      x: i * 100,
      y: i2 * 100
    });
  }
}
map.forEach(function output(value, key) {
  console.log(key, value);
});
```

P.S. Наверно, правильней было бы писать такой код синтаксисом ES6+, но не хочу перегружать ТС информацией

Comment: а куда тут e6 можно вставить?

Comment: @Grundy, не "вставить", а использовать синтаксис.

Comment: я имел ввиду, какой синтаксис тут еще можно использовать? что-то кроме let/const в объявлениях и стрелочной функции в callback, не могу придумать

Comment: @Grundy, Я про перечисленное вами и говорил.

Answer (score 2):

В начале вашего кода добавьте var array = []; Но действия по заполнения массива с ключами вида -1--1 выглядят подозрительно.

А не выводит потому что у вас циклы не останавливаются.

Comment: ` var array = []` - ничего не исправит.

Comment: эти ключи текстовые,как строка, нет разницы что использовать.